# How to draw slices in semicircle shape layers in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, cashapelayer

I have drawn the semicircle shape  by using following code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bezierPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height/2) radius:150 startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:YES];
     CAShapeLayer *progressLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [progressLayer setPath:bezierPath.CGPath];
    [progressLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1. alpha:.2].CGColor];
    [progressLayer setFillColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:67.0/255.0 green:144.0/255.0 blue:246.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
    [progressLayer setLineWidth:.7 * self.bounds.size.width];
    [[self layer] addSublayer:progressLayer];
      // [self drawWheel];
  }
```

I want to draw a slices like pie in a semicircle using objective-c that should match exactly like image as shown below

[image]

Can anyone suggest me any solution please

Comment: What I'd do? Use a piece of paper and a pen. Isolate each points, try to understand how to get its locations, try to understand how to go from one point to the next one (is it a line, is it an arc? if yes, what's the center, what's the radius, what's the total angle)? etc. Because it's just about maths/logic, and it's quite "long" to do (so a little too broad). Note that your image has a slight "harder" (another little difficulty) point it's that the small circle hasn't the same center has the big one.

Comment: It is a arc I guess(i.e. pie slice is clickable). I actually followed the tutorial  https://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit. But I am finding difficulty to get the mid point of circle to draw the arc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your `drawRect(_:)`

```
let radius = min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2;
let center = CGPoint.init(x: bounds.size.width / 2, y: bounds.size.height / 2)
let sliceCount = 6;

let slicePath = UIBezierPath.init()
slicePath.lineWidth = 1;
slicePath.move(to: center)

var angle: CGFloat = 0 - (CGFloat.pi / 2);
var interval: CGFloat = (CGFloat.pi) / CGFloat(sliceCount)



for i in 0 ... sliceCount {
    let x = center.x + (radius * cos(angle))
    let y = center.y + (radius * sin(angle))
    slicePath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: x, y: y))
    slicePath.move(to: center)
    angle -= interval;
}

UIColor.white.setStroke()
slicePath.stroke()
```

Here is the result.[image]

**Updated**
Another code that's very similar to your goal

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let radius = min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2;
    let center = CGPoint.init(x: bounds.size.width, y: bounds.size.height / 2)
    let sliceCount = 6;

    let semiCirclePath = UIBezierPath.init()
    semiCirclePath.move(to: center)
    semiCirclePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi + (CGFloat.pi / 2) , clockwise: true)
    semiCirclePath.close()
    UIColor.blue.setFill()
    semiCirclePath.fill()



    let slicePath = UIBezierPath.init()
    slicePath.lineWidth = 1;
    slicePath.move(to: center)

    var angle: CGFloat = 0 - (CGFloat.pi / 2);
    var interval: CGFloat = (CGFloat.pi) / CGFloat(sliceCount)



    for i in 0 ... sliceCount {
        let x = center.x + (radius * cos(angle))
        let y = center.y + (radius * sin(angle))
        slicePath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: x, y: y))
        slicePath.move(to: center)
        angle -= interval;
    }

    UIColor.white.setStroke()
    slicePath.stroke()

    semiCirclePath.removeAllPoints()
    semiCirclePath.move(to: center)
    semiCirclePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: 30, startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi + (CGFloat.pi / 2) , clockwise: true)
    UIColor.lightGray.setFill()
    semiCirclePath.fill()
}
```

Here what it looks like,

[image]

**Updated second time**
For the one that's completely looked like

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let radius = min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2;
    let center = CGPoint.init(x: bounds.size.width, y: bounds.size.height / 2)
    let selectedSliceIndex = 2;
    let sliceCount = 6;

    let slicePath = UIBezierPath.init()
    let selectedSlicePath = UIBezierPath.init()
    slicePath.lineWidth = 1;
    slicePath.move(to: center)

    var angle: CGFloat = 0 - (CGFloat.pi / 2);
    let interval: CGFloat = (CGFloat.pi) / CGFloat(sliceCount)

    for i in 0 ... sliceCount {
        let x = center.x + (radius * cos(angle))
        let y = center.y + (radius * sin(angle))
        slicePath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: x, y: y))
        slicePath.move(to: center)


        if i == selectedSliceIndex {
            selectedSlicePath.move(to: center)
            selectedSlicePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: angle - interval, endAngle: angle, clockwise: true)
            selectedSlicePath.close()
        }

        angle -= interval;
    }

    // outer blue circle
    let semiCirclePath = UIBezierPath.init()
    semiCirclePath.move(to: center)
    semiCirclePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi + (CGFloat.pi / 2) , clockwise: true)
    semiCirclePath.close()
    UIColor.blue.setFill()
    semiCirclePath.fill()

    // lines
    UIColor.white.setStroke()
    slicePath.stroke()

    // selected slice
    UIColor.lightGray.setFill()
    selectedSlicePath.fill()
    UIColor.clear.setFill()

    // inner gray circle
    semiCirclePath.removeAllPoints()
    semiCirclePath.move(to: center)
    semiCirclePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: 30, startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi + (CGFloat.pi / 2) , clockwise: true)
    UIColor.lightGray.setFill()
    semiCirclePath.fill()

}
```

[image]

You might need to adjust some values to look beautiful.

I Moved the view's frame inside ViewController FYI.

Comment: Great. Superb...  it's working thanks. Actually I am doing it in Objective-c and converting it to objective-c

Comment: Can I add text to it using CATextlayer?

Comment: @sathyarakesh I haven't tried that kind of UI with CATextLayer but with UILabel. Just use Trig functions and CGAffineTransform over [CATextLayer] or [UILabel] and layout properly.  It should be working fine.

Comment: @sathyarakesh kindly share objective-c code, I need to the same semicircle with slices and actions on item